# How do i make it so that a space is added every 4 digits

Tags: python

So I'm currently working on a decimal-to-binary converter and am running into a formatting issue where I can't seem to add a space every four digits. currently, it is adding the "space"(at the moment it's a 5) to the end of the string. any suggestions are welcome.

```
decimal = int(input("Enter Binary Number: "))

binary = ""

while decimal > 0:
  
    remainder = decimal % 2
    binary += str(remainder)
    decimal = int(decimal / 2)
  

reverse = binary[::-1]

counter = 0

for i in reverse:
      counter+=1
      if counter == 4:
            reverse+="5"
            counter=0
```

print("The Binary Number Is: ", reverse)

Comment: 'reverse' is your entire string.  What makes you think that '5' will get inserted into the middle of the string?  You're not using `i` at the moment.  Do you mean to be using `i` as a position and inserting into `reverse`?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do what you're doing, but going with your code, here's a fixed version that I think does what you want:

```
decimal = int(input("Enter Binary Number: "))
binary = ""

while decimal > 0:
    remainder = decimal % 2
    binary += str(remainder)
    decimal = int(decimal / 2)

reverse = binary[::-1]

counter = 0

newstr = ''

for i in reverse:
    newstr += i
    counter += 1
    if counter == 4:
        newstr += "5"
        counter = 0

print(newstr)
```

Result:

```
Enter Binary Number: 255
1111511115
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal = int(input("Enter Binary Number: "))

binary = ""

while decimal > 0:  
    remainder = decimal % 2
    binary += str(remainder)
    decimal = int(decimal / 2)
 
binary = [binary[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(binary), 4)]
binary_joined = " ".join(binary)
result = binary_joined[::-1]

print("The Binary Number Is:", result)
```

Result Example 1

```
Enter Binary Number: 1234
The Binary Number Is: 100 1101 0010
```

Result Example 2

```
Enter Binary Number: 128
The Binary Number Is: 1000 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I explain step by step. First part I only replicate your code, my focus was on getting the spaces:

```
decimal = int(input("Enter Binary Number: "))

binary = ""

while decimal > 0:
  
    remainder = decimal % 2
    binary += str(remainder)
    decimal = int(decimal / 2)
  
reverse = binary[::-1]
# Up to here I only replicate your code

# Now, we add the spaces
# Get the quantity of numbers
num_lenght = len(reverse)
# Get the quantity of zeros we will add at the begining
zeros = 0
remaining = num_lenght % 4
if remaining:
    zeros = 4 - num_lenght % 4
    reverse = zeros*"0" + reverse
# Get the quantity of divisions
divisions = num_lenght + zeros
# Have new string with the spaces
result = ""
for i in range(0, divisions):
    # We add the substrings with the space
    j = i * 4
    result += reverse[j:j+4] + " "
# Delete whitespaces at end
result = result.strip()
print(f"The Binary Number Is: {result}")
```

The result for random decimal number 104 will look like this:

```
The Binary Number Is: 0110 1000
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
decimal = int(input("Enter Binary Number: "))

binary = ""
cnt = 0
while decimal > 0:
    remainder = decimal % 2
    binary += str(remainder)
    cnt += 1
    if cnt % 4 == 0:
        binary += str(" ")
    decimal = int(decimal / 2)

while len(binary.replace(" ","")) % 4 != 0:
    binary += str(0)
print(binary[::-1])
```

Comment: This is amazingly complicated to not be accompanied by a justifying explanation.  I also don't think it does what the OP wants as a result.